# Naming the project containing only interfaces

Tags: c#, naming, projects-and-solutions, project-structure, naming-standards

I've extracted interfaces from my repository classes, like ICustomerRepository, IProductRepository and so on. The project which contains the repositories is named X.DataAccessLayer. Should I call the project with the interfaces X.DataAccessLayerInterfaces, or what is better?

And I definitely have to keep the interfaces in a separate project (I have 2 projects with implementations of these interfaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever name you can think of that correctly describes the contents and does not feel too long.

Personally, X.DataAccessLayerInterfaces feels too long for me, so I would probably opt for X.DataAccessInterfaces, but otherwise there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I'd say we're at a point in time to use DAL.

Answer (score 7):

The naming pattern also depends on your other projects. Depending on the contents of your implementation projects it could be something like this:

- X.DataAccessLayer
- X.DataAccessLayer.Sql
- X.DataAccessLayer.Oracle

PS: I would drop 'Layer' as well, unless you have a mix of independent libraries and actual layers.

Comment: @user278618 no problem!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with x.DataAccess.Interface and have your implementations as x.DataAccess.Oracle, x.DataAccess.EF or whatever.

Comment: Your answer would be stronger if you provided supporting evidence or reasoning to justify the claim you've made.